# How to disable the onListItemClick() action if the gestureDetector action happend

Tags: android, touch-event, gesture-recognition, ontouchlistener

I have read the post: [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection) and implemented gesture detection. But I have the follow problem. After the action **onFling()** occurred, the **onListItemClick()** is calling. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the **onFling()** method. This method **should return true** if operation completed successfully, otherwise calls onClickItemClicked()

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
        float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    if (e2.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

        return false;
    }

    try {
        float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
        float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();

        if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            return false;

        // Left swipe
        if (diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            listener.onLeftSwipe();

            // Right swipe
        } else if (-diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            listener.onRightSwipe();
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
   view.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
   .....
   view.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
}
```

Maybe helps